# PostgreSQL - for each loop

Tags: postgresql, for-loop

I need something like this

```
SELECT
foreach(service IN (SELECT tbl_services.service_name FROM tbl_services))
    COUNT(CASE WHEN service=ANY(tbl_providers.provided_services) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM tbl_providers;
```

Is there any specific solution for implementing this type of for each in sql? thanks

Comment: When you start thinking in "loops" in SQL you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query gives you same result (number of services provided by any provider):

```
SELECT count(distinct s.service)
FROM tbl_services s
INNER JOIN tbl_providers p ON p.provided_services @> ARRAY[s.service]::varchar[]
```

Comment: thank you kind sir for your answer. p.provided_services is an array, including many services each provider able to provide. So it's not possible to join them.

Comment: @pouriadaneshvar would something like `INNER JOIN tbl_providers p ON s.service = ANY(p.provided_services)` work?

Comment: @pouriadaneshvar please, see updated query above. Made if  provided_services array contains service.